# Unable to calculate mean for each day in ggplot facet?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, facet

## My dataset

I have a dataset speedtest.csv that looks something like this:

```
Date,Time,Download,Upload
2023/10/01,00:00:00,34957192.9969772,20046840.2637393
2023/10/01,00:20:00,35826556.3982541,36143231.5378943
2023/10/01,00:40:00,27695436.936076,4957720.87281617
...
...
2023/10/02,01:00:00,22575345.5295727,10335897.5917135
2023/10/02,01:20:00,15805169.0654657,6179704.32589804
2023/10/02,01:40:00,31638270.9069979,15951432.6154521
...
...
2023/10/03,05:00:00,31366450.4288069,4476811.81028971
2023/10/03,05:20:00,10709016.6772629,8848402.0645949
2023/10/03,05:40:00,32722858.0348491,2045099.79491319
...
...
```

## My current code

Given below is the my current code that is able to process and output the data using facets in ggplot. For this exercise, I am trying to generate the ggplot within a single code-block using pipes.

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-read.csv("speedtest.csv", header = TRUE)

df%>%
  select(Date,Time, Upload, Download)%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Upload", "Download"),
               names_to = "Parameter", values_to = "Value")%>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d"),
         Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=(Value/8000000), colour=Parameter))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Date, ncol = 3, nrow = 2)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue","orange"))+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "4 hours",
                   date_labels = "%H:%M")+
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab("Speed (Mbyte/s)")+
  ylim(c(0,5))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid = element_line(linetype = "dashed"))

ggsave("Speedtest_Figure.png")
```

## Current output

That produces an output that looks something like this:

[image: Current_output]

## Requested change

Is it possible to add the text in each facet like:

```
Mean Download: NNN
Mean Upload: MMM
```

Where NNN and MMM are the mean download and upload speed for each day that will change for each facet. I want to do this within the single block of code, within the pipes if possible.

## My attempt

I have gone for the non-optimal method of creating different objects and then using `geom_text` to input the information in the plot.

I created a separate object `Mean.dat`

```
Mean.dat<-df%>%
  select(Date,Time, Upload, Download)%>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d"),
         Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))%>%
  group_by(Date)%>%
  summarise(mean(Download)/8000000)
```

and then added this bit to the main code:

```
  geom_text(data=Mean.dat,
            aes(x=14, y=5, label=`mean(Download)/8e+06`), 
            colour="black", inherit.aes=FALSE, hjust = -1)
```

But I get the error message:

`Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`

### Other resources

I have referred to the following sources:

[Add text to a faceted plot in ggplot2 with dates on X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458349/add-text-to-a-faceted-plot-in-ggplot2-with-dates-on-x-axis)

[Creating a facet_wrap plot with ggplot2 with different annotations in each plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050610/creating-a-facet-wrap-plot-with-ggplot2-with-different-annotations-in-each-plot)

[Annotate ggplot2 facets with number of observations per facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239843/annotate-ggplot2-facets-with-number-of-observations-per-facet)

[How to add annotation on each facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499396/how-to-add-annotation-on-each-facet)

[add unique text to each facet ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575318/add-unique-text-to-each-facet-ggplot)

I have tried to modify the code in previous attempts, but the date-time problem seems to be persistent.

## Addendum

To make the code more reproducible, I was asked to provide a snippet of my data using `dput()`.

Here is the output for `dput(df[c(1:5, 10:15, 20:25, 30:35, 40:41),])`

```
structure(list(Date = c("2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", 
"2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", 
"2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", 
"2023/11/04", "2023/11/04", "2023/11/05", "2023/11/05", "2023/11/05", 
"2023/11/05", "2023/11/05", "2023/11/05", "2023/11/05", "2023/11/05", 
"2023/11/05", "2023/11/05"), Time = c("13:05:32", "13:20:03", 
"13:40:05", "14:20:03", "14:40:03", "17:20:03", "17:40:02", "18:20:03", 
"18:40:03", "19:20:04", "19:40:03", "22:20:03", "22:40:03", "23:20:03", 
"23:40:03", "00:20:03", "00:40:03", "03:20:03", "03:40:03", "04:20:03", 
"04:40:03", "05:20:03", "05:40:03", "08:20:03", "08:40:03"), 
    Download = c(34957192.9969772, 35826556.3982541, 27695436.936076, 
    32785866.6580349, 34373754.7935802, 29644745.5493678, 31936459.8397868, 
    32782764.8827361, 31366450.4288069, 10709016.6772629, 32722858.0348491, 
    34821984.5787153, 28379214.5120736, 26820887.0474698, 31839780.4165726, 
    32066886.2373525, 33440458.6440393, 28113353.9035434, 26284377.6573347, 
    29154520.6902359, 34918254.2123446, 21598680.1274404, 20700752.1868799, 
    34638409.416459, 34572097.5993048), Upload = c(20046840.2637393, 
    36143231.5378943, 4957720.87281616, 15688120.7580889, 35845959.9473685, 
    18072485.390123, 9069468.67273845, 6973860.4270036, 4476811.81028971, 
    8848402.0645949, 2045099.79491319, 23198345.7376053, 31702122.0677866, 
    11711052.7340582, 12556196.1275965, 28941390.4693129, 21543697.8944099, 
    12966120.4632239, 28660937.1396553, 28476185.8084195, 16678584.8862002, 
    29032008.7959507, 17276854.3732636, 36479144.7960276, 37478780.5131303
    )), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 40L, 41L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: As your are using `scale_x_datetime` you have to specify the x position in geom_text as a datetime, i.e. `x=14` will not work.

Comment: For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by sharing a snippet of your data via `dput()`.

Comment: @stefan: I tried `x="14:00"` as well, but get the same error.

Comment: `"14:00"` is a character string not a datetime. Try with `x = as.POSIXct("14:00", format = "%H:%M")`

Comment: @stefan: This worked! How do I mark you as the correct answer or give you points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment, the issue with your second approach is that you have to specify the `x` axis value for your labels as a datetime too, i.e. do `x = as.POSIXct("14:00", format = "%H:%M")`.

However, as you mentioned that your preferred or optimal way would be to do all the computations in one pipeline instead of using a second dataset below is one approach which uses a `stat_summary` to add the labels.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(Date, Time, Upload, Download) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("Upload", "Download"),
    names_to = "Parameter", values_to = "Value"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d"),
    Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = (Value / 8000000), colour = Parameter)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(
    data = ~filter(.x, Parameter == "Download"),
    geom = "text",
    aes(
      x = as.POSIXct("14:00", format = "%H:%M"),
      y = stage(Value / 8000000, after_stat = 5),
      label = after_stat(round(y, 2))
    ),
    fun = mean, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~Date, ncol = 3, nrow = 2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "orange")) +
  scale_x_datetime(
    date_breaks = "4 hours",
    date_labels = "%H:%M"
  ) +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Speed (Mbyte/s)") +
  ylim(c(0, 5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid = element_line(linetype = "dashed")
  )
```

[image]